# Register a domain with NIC

Tags: nameserver, nic

I recently bought a `.es` domain for the purpose of creating a domain hack.  I registered the domain with esreg.com (SANE Systems, apparently).  My card was charged, but the domain is listed as not registered.  I have not yet been able to get in contact with them.

Their website seems to have a small form to register the site and to specify the nameservers, but when I fill it out it says "You have to specify the NIC handles first."  I don't know how to get those.  They have for example a box that says "Owner" with an example of `SK86-ESNIC-F4`.  I have another website so I may have this information, but I don't know how to get it.

Comment: Tried contacting their support?

Comment: @LucasKauffman yes, their phone number doesn't work and they haven't replied to my email (only been a day) so maybe it's a scam

Comment: were you able to solve this issue? I registered a .es name today esreg.com and am experiencing the same issue. Emailed them but no answer yet. Thanks.

Comment: @xbora I was unable to get in contact with them either by email or phone.  I called my bank and they reverted the charge.  I would have liked the domain, but I'm not paying for nothing either.  Let me know if you can get it to work.

Comment: I believe it is scam. I've tried to register a domain with them, they would not do that, neither would they answer email, and the phone on the site is a phone of a shop of some sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DNS authority in Spain is [NIC.ES](http://www.nic.es/) 
They maintain a [list of authoried regirstrars](https://www.nic.es/list-registrars/agenteRegistrador/1447) 
I am afraid, esreg.com is not listed here so be careful and take your measures, it could be an untrusted site. I have asked directly to NIC.ES to confirm this issue, awaiting for response. Will update with their response.

Comment: Just confirmed by NIC.ES. esreg.com is not an authorized registrar!